# Is there a way to test with JUnit this project?

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I created this rock scissors paper project

```
public class Rocksciccorspaper {
    private static final int R = 1;
    private static final int S = 2;
    private static final int P = 3;
    private int rounds;

    public Rocksciccorspaper(int rounds) {
        this.rounds = rounds;
    }

    private String winner(int userSelect, int botSelect) {
        if (userSelect == botSelect) {
            return "draw";
        } else if (botSelect - userSelect == 1 || botSelect - userSelect == -2) {
            return "Congrats, you won.";
        } else {
            return "You lose.";
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int playedRounds = 0;
        while (playedRounds < rounds) {
            System.out.print("choose Rock(1), Sciccors(2), Paper(3): ");
            int userSelect = sc.nextInt();
            int botSelect = new Random().nextInt(3) + 1;
            System.out.println("You Choose: "
                    + selectionDetect(userSelect));
            System.out.println("Bot Choose: "
                    + selectionDetect(botSelect));
            System.out.println(winner(userSelect, botSelect));
            System.out.println();
            playedRounds++;
        }
        sc.close();
    }

    private String selectionDetect(int selection) {
        if (selection == R) {
            return "Rock (1)";
        } else if (selection == S) {
            return "Sciccors (2)";
        } else if (selection == P) {
            return "Paper (3)";
        } else {
            return "Invalid Selection (" + selection + ")";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rocksciccorspaper rocksciccorsPaper = new Rocksciccorspaper(3);
        rocksciccorsPaper.start();
    }

}
```

I want to test it. The first function which I want to test is the winner function. I think that's one of the important functions.

I tried something but it doesn't work well. I'm not sure how to test the selection in my if condition.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class RocksciccorspaperTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to perform integration(data-driven) tests or Mock tests with JUnit?

Comment: I think Mock Tests with JUnit @Pawan.Java

Comment: So you have to create a dependency of your Rocksciccorspaper class into your Test class first. Then you have to parse data which you would desire to obtain as a result into your winner function. Finally use assertEquals to compare the expected value to the obtained value.

Comment: You need a good tutorial to start with Junit, consult this link: https://www.arhohuttunen.com/junit-5-getting-started/

Comment: "winner" is tested by passing in ask combinations of inputs and making sure its return value matches your expectations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is difficult to think of a test, then a Test First approach is often useful. Put your existing code aside. Write a test. Write enough code to satisfy that test (perhaps copy and paste your old code; perhaps not). Refactor if you wish. Repeat until done.

Test First aside:

The method `winner` is probably going to be your first target to test. It needs to be made accessible to the test. In this case that is easy to do by making it `static` and `public` and moving it to a separate class. Including UI text makes that test fragile (say, you decide to capitalise `"draw"`), so consider using an enum instead of `String`.

The actual code for testing winner will be something like:

```
import static mypackage.Decision.*;
// ...
    assertEquals("draw", winner(R, R));
```

There's only nine possible combinations, so exhaustive testing is trvial.

As well as UI, global state makes testing (and everything else) hacky. Consider replacing `System.in` and `System.out` with parameters. The globals themselves only need to be referenced right up in `main`.

Comment: Thanks mate. That will help me to continue.